# open link and refresh the new opened link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, refresh

here is my following problem:

I need to open an link after opening the link, the newly opened page should refresh(like pressing F5).

Backround: the qtranslate plugin in wordpress doesn't work so propper, the page translates but not the menu. After I press F5 the menu is also translated.

I thought that maybe I can solve the problem to build a custom link which opens the page and presses F5/refress it after loading.

```
<a href="URL/en/"  onClick="location.reload(true)" /> <img src="/img/en.png"></a>
<a href="URL" /> <img src="/img/hu.png"></a>
```

I google I found some attempt's but firefox does't like them ....

Comment: @user2764629 - What problem are you facing ?

Comment: the menu dosen't translate so I need to refresh the whole page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setTimeout`

```
          setTimeout(function(){
          window.setTimeout(function()
          {location.reload()
           },3000);
```

**[Example Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/dFJn8/25/)**

Comment: works so far! just now somehow it seems the links are not working in chrome and firefox but in IE! only the language flags are showing but no effect. the first time it worked perfectly. I'm really confused...

Comment: NEED help!!!!

why the links are not working anymore, just in IE... I'm realy confused

Comment: Paste some code ..Which links are you talking about ?? Are you talkin of demo of mine??

Comment: ok, now it seems to work! I just putted the the div with the flags somewhere else! - 

thank you @Vaibs_Cool